# ¿Puede una cena "ir"?

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, colombia

I want to wish someone well regarding her planned dinner.  I believe the literal translation of

> I hope the dinner **goes** well

is

> Espero que la cena **vaya** bien

But I have doubts if this will be understood correctly.  The reader is Colombian.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Como te vas, Como te va, Como se va](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12732/como-te-vas-como-te-va-como-se-va)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence will be understood. The verb *ir* can be used colloquially to describe how well or bad something goes. In the DLE (the reference dictionary in Spanish):

> [*ir bien*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy)
>
> *loc. verb. coloq.* Dicho de una cosa: Desarrollarse satisfactoriamente.

That is, when something develops satisfactorily.

You can also use it in other situations:

- > ¿Cómo va el trabajo? // How is your job going?
- > ¿Cómo va todo? // How is everything?
- > ¿Cómo te va en la nueva casa? // How are you doing in the new house?

Comment: I would add that even *ir* by itself can work sometimes, by extension of its meaning "to go" > "to run, to work, to function". *¿Va?* = "Does it work?"

Comment: Pero en el ejemplo especifico, no suena mas natural decir *espero que te vaya bien la cena*? O, al menos, *espero que la cena **te** vaya bien*?

Comment: @terdon, la frase me suena natural así como está. Igual podría ser algo regional, en cuyo caso también vale porque la pregunta establece que el lector es de Colombia. Aún así me atrevería a decir que suena natural en otras partes. Otra opción para acercarnos a la opción que propones sería: "Espero que te vaya bien con [lo de] la cena"

Comment: Yo he escuchado "te vaya" pero deseo que la cena esté bien para ella y sus padres.

Comment: @mauricio bueno puede que sea regional pero más probable que se trata de ignorancia mía.

Comment: @walen yes, I was assuming she was the host of the dinner, in which case the pronoun would, I think, apply since it would be *her* dinner.

Comment: you can try to explore different ways to wish the same, 
if it's a challenge :"Te deseo todo el exito del mundo en tu cena"--"I whish you all the success in the world for your dinner"  
if it's a family reunion "Deseo que tengas una bonita cena con tu familia/amigos" --
"i wish you a nice/sweet dinner with your friends and family" 

don't be afraid of getting too personal when using Spanish